# Extracting N JSON objects contained in a single line from a text file in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parsing

I have a huge text file that contains several JSON objects inside of it that I want to parse into a csv file. Just because i'm dealing with someone else's data I cannot really change the format its being delivered in.

Since I dont know how many objects JSON objects I just can create a couple set of dictionaries, wrap them in a list and then `json.loads()` the list.

Also, since all the objects are in a single text line I can't a regex expression to separete each individual json object and then put them on a list.(It's a super complicated and sometimes triple nested json at some points.

Here's, my current code

```
def json_to_csv(text_file_name,desired_csv_name):
    #Cleans up a bit of the text file
    file = fileinput.FileInput(text_file_name, inplace=True)
    ile = fileinput.FileInput(text_file_name, inplace=True)
    for line in file:
        sys.stdout.write(line.replace(u'\'', u'"'))
    for line in ile:
        sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r'("[\s\w]*)"([\s\w]*")', r"\1\2", line))
    #try to load the text file to content var
    with open(text_file_name, "rb") as fin:
        content = json.load(fin)
        #Rest of the logic using the json data in content
        #that uses it for the desired csv format
```

This code gives a `ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 159816` because there is more than one object there.

I seen similar questions in Google and StackOverflow. But none of those solutions none because of the fact that it's just one really long line  in a text file and I dont know how many objects there are in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to split apart the highest level braces you could do something like

```
string = '{"NextToken": {"value": "...'
objects = eval("[" + string + "]")
```

and then parse each item in the list.

Comment: dicts cant (pre 3.7) be guaranteed to maintain a specific order

Comment: That give a `Syntax Error` probably because i'm reading the data from a file and not as a string from a variable